# nilpotent elements elements give rise to inverse.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

If a left ideal $\mathscr{U} \subseteq R$ is nil, then $\mathscr{U} \subseteq rad(R)$.

## proof

Let $y \in \mathscr{U}$ where $\mathscr{U}$ is nil. Then $y$ is nilpotent and $xy \in \mathscr{U}$ for any $x \in R$. It follows that $1-xy$ has an inverse $\sum_{i=0}^\infty (xy)^ii$ and since $1-xy$ has, in particular, a left inverse $y \in rad(R)$.

## confusion

How is $\sum_{i=0}^\infty (xy)^ii$ even well-defined. I see the even terms will all be $0$ since $(xy)^2$ is 0 but we have no notion of convergence for such an infinite sum. How one would even verify or construct this as he inverse I am completely unclear on.

Comment: What would make the even terms distinct from the odd terms? And why is $(xy)^2=0$?

Comment: $\mathscr{U}$ is nil and so $x \in R$ and $y \in \mathscr{U}$ we hae $xy \in \mathscr{U}$ and so $xy$ is nilpotent. Hence, even powers of the above would give multiples of $(xy)^2=0$

Comment: This is not true. $(xy)^2$ doesn't have to be $0$. And any power $(xy)^i$ is a multiple of $(xy)^2$, not just when $i$ is even.

Comment: Of course it is. I don't know what I'm saying apparently

Comment: (I meant "any power of $(xy)^i$ with $i \geq 2$".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of that argument you can be a bit more concrete. Let $k$ be an integer such that $(xy)^{k}=0$ (which exists because $xy$ is nilpotent). Define
$$u=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}(xy)^{i}\in R,$$
and note that
$$u(1-xy)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}(xy)^{i}-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}(xy)^{i}=1-(xy)^{k}=1,$$
so that $u$ is a left inverse of $xy$. Since $x$ was arbitrary you can conclude that $y\in \operatorname{Rad}(R)$ and you get the desired result.